# Is it possible to split a plotting device screen in R without losing the previous plot?

Tags: r, plot

Is there an underlying reason within R's architecture that prevents the use of a function that updates a plotting device with a second high-level plotting function?

Matlab has some functions, like `colorbar`, that seem to work in this way - by shifting the original plot to make room for the new element: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html

It seems to me that this would require splitting the screen (e.g. `split.screen`, `layout`) while moving the previous plot to one of the subareas.

For this to work, I guess that the calls to the previous device must be stored in order to update the new split screen - or is there another way?

Comment: if you use `ggplot2` you can get back the call to the current plot with `p <- last_plot()`

Comment: @clemlaflemme - Something like that for base graphics is indeed be what I would be interested in.

Comment: have you had a look at `dev.copy(...)` ?

Comment: The base graphics are designed to write, not erase.  If you want a fully editable graphics window, you'll have to play with `rgl` to access the OpenGL graphics library.    In the meantime,  you can set up the base graphics window by defining sub-areas **before** you start plotting.

Comment: @clemlaflemme - Thanks for the idea. I think `dev.copy` is really only saving an image rather than the underlying data contained in the plot.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - thanks for the information. I would of course set these things up before for a final plot. I guess this functionality would be more interesting during data exploration, where you can add plotting components on the fly.  If you have a simple example of your suggested OpenGL idea, I would be most appreciative to see it.

Comment: @Marcinthebox sure but I was hoping sth like `dev.new(); par(mfrow=c(1,2)); dev.set(2); dev.copy(which=3)`would copy the first plot into the half of the new one. But instead it totally replaces it

Comment: Hi. Do you have a simple example of two plots you'd like to  combine in this way?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - maybe something like the `colorbar` function in matlab does? e.g. `image(volcano); colorbar(add.to.existing=TRUE)`

Comment: AFAIK, this simply isn't possible using base graphics. The **grid** package does support this to some extent via its `grid.frame()` and `grid.pack()` functions. And, using the nifty **gridGraphics** package, you can capture individual base plots as **grid** grobs, that you could then pack together. For example: `library(gridGraphics); library(grid); plot(1:10); grid.echo(); x <- grid.grab(); grid.newpage(); grid.frame(name="ff"); grid.pack("ff", x); grid.pack("ff",  x, side="right", width=unit(3,"cm")); grid.pack("ff", x, side="bottom", height=unit(3, "cm"))`.